# What is an optimal coffee to water ratio for pour-overs?

Tags: pour-over, chemex

Does anyone have any good recommendations for an optimal coffee to water ratio for pour-overs? I am not interested in cold brews and I use a Chemex carafe with Chemex filters.

I generally prefer light to medium-dark roasts, but I am open to trying other roasts that tend towards the darker side.

I would guess that dark roasts may require a lower coffee to water ratio than lighter roasts.

Comment: James Hoffmann recommends around 60-65 grams of coffee per 1000 grams of water, check out his video on [the V60](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AI4ynXzkSQo) and [the Chemex](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ikt-X5x7yoc) if you haven't already.

Answer (score -1):

This is going to be unpopular but my routine doesn't really involve measuring much.  I want get the brewing over with ASAP so I can drink my coffee.

1. Prime the filter with hot water and pour out water
2. Put in ground coffee, I just use 6 TBSP for the 8 cup classic
3. Prime grounds by pouring just enough in to stir them up and get wet
4. Wait for gas to release (should have a nice cone of grounds)
5. Pour water into the center of the grinds and then circulate as water rises
6. Wait until brewed coffee gets to the belly button of the chemex
7. Pour more water in until it is about 1/4 inch to the top
8. Let drain out and enjoy

I just go a bit bigger with my scoops if I'm looking for more of dark brew.  My goal here is to control the output so that when finished I have enough coffee for about two pint glasses.  Thy key is that belly button which I'm guessing is the half-way mark.

Comment: Considering that the asker explicitly asked for a ratio, this doesn’t seem to be a useful answer? If it’s an answer at all, in the SE sense?

Comment: I agree.  I am trying to show that you do not have to overcomplicate things to get good results the Chemex brewer is designed to provide visual feedback on when to do what in the brewing process.